# Capital letters and punctuation mark in Python

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard

I am working on an application which has to write text on the screen based on the input coming from a keyboard written in an another Android app.
The server on the PC is written in Python and, actually I am using the keyboard package to deal with key events.

Here the sample code:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write('a')
keyboard.write('b')
keyboard.write('1')
keyboard.write('!')
keyboard.write('\"')
```

Here the result:

```
ab112
```

As you can see, I have issues with punctuation mark that need the combination SHIFT + .

Comment: Why can't you just use press and release? Or just print?

Comment: I tested before and it did not work. Now I solved using the last version of the library from Github repository